# Get records which were not updated the day before

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a list of items which were not updated the day before.

I currently have...

```
 SELECT     dbo.aboProducts.asin, dbo.aboProducts.sku
 FROM       dbo.aboProducts INNER JOIN
            dbo.LowestPrices ON dbo.aboProducts.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin
 WHERE     (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate <= DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

This however returns nothing. If i change the <= to >= i get results from the last 24 hours. I just need to return any items which were NOT updated, and leave the ones that were updated alone.

Comment: The initial query looks good: update timestamp should be 1 day less then current. Also try `GETDATE() - 1`. Is time part meaningful?

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT     aboProducts.asin, aboProducts.sku
FROM       dbo.aboProducts 
where aboProducts.asin 
not in(
     select aboProducts.asin 
     FROM       dbo.aboProducts 
     INNER JOIN
                dbo.LowestPrices 
     ON aboProducts.asin = LowestPrices.productAsin
     WHERE     (LowestPrices.priceDate >= DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks fine, assuming every Product has at least one entry in LowestPrices. Do you actually have any items that weren't updated?

Comment: yeah, there were a few :( not sure why though. still testing that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT     dbo.aboProducts.asin, dbo.aboProducts.sku
 FROM       dbo.aboProducts INNER JOIN
            dbo.LowestPrices ON dbo.aboProducts.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin
 WHERE     (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate != DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))
```